# Powershell String keep CR & LF

Tags: mysql, string, powershell, newline, quotes

I want to Insert a Blob in a MySQL Database via "MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection", it works fine but Powershell removes the Newline Characters from my Variable:

```
$configString = Get-Content config.xml 
$configString > test5.xml
$strAddConfig = "INSERT INTO config_xml(Version,ConfigXML,MD5,Comment,ClientMinVersion) VALUES('2','" + $($configString) + "','$configMD5','BLABLA','5.0.0.0')"
```

When I pipe the $configString variable into a Textfile, the CR&LF characters will keep, also when I input the blob via copy paste the  Newline characters wil considered. I tried the "strAddConfig" line with different Quote combinations, but I wasn`t successful.

Thanks for help

Comment: Remove the single-quotes around `'$configMD5'`

Comment: I tried this: "INSERT INTO config_xml(Version,ConfigXML,MD5,Comment,ClientMinVersion) VALUES('2', " + $($configString) + ",$configMD5,'BLABLA','5.0.0.0')" but got the exception: "Unknown column 'F4F0B5F96C03B548958D9E1C3D4949F2' in 'field list'" It takes the Hash as an Field?

Comment: Otherwise when I run this: "INSERT INTO config_xml(Version,ConfigXML,MD5,Comment,ClientMinVersion) VALUES('2',$configString,$configMD5,'BLABLA','5.0.0.0')" I got: "Fatal error encountered during command execution."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sh
# Read the text content *as a single, multi-line string*, using -Raw
$configString = Get-Content -Raw config.xml

# Use an expandable here-string for better formatting.
$strAddConfig = @"
INSERT INTO config_xml(Version,ConfigXML,MD5,Comment,ClientMinVersion)
VALUES('2','$configString','$configMD5','BLABLA','5.0.0.0')
"@
```

Your (primary) problem was the use of `Get-Content config.xml` *without* `-Raw`, which stored an *array* of lines in `$configString`, and when an array is used in an [*expandable string*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375)  (`"..."`, with string interpolation), its (stringified) elements are *space*-separated:

```sh
PS> $array = 'one', 'two'; "$array"
one two
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, with get-content -raw it works fine :)

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Ahmet.B; please also see the explanation I've just added to the answer.